# AWS Cloudwatch Metrics - How to get S3 / Elastic storage totals in ALL buckets from API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, geckoboard

It is straightforward enough to pull data for how much is in a particular S3 bucket. I am trying to connect Geckoboard to monitor S3 data usage, is there a way to use cloudwatch metrics to access how much storage is in use overall on our account? We have many buckets and I just need a total, not a number for each bucket, which is as far as I have gotten.

Thanks

Chris "AWS console is frustratingly unintuitive" H.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite the solution I was hoping for, but it is possible to collect this data using the graph metrics in Cloudwatch.